# JAXB unmarshalling without XmlRootElement annotation?

Tags: java, jaxb

Is there any way we can un-marshall for a class without @XmlRootElement annotation? Or are we obligated to enter the annotation?

for example:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

and let the unmarshalling code for properly annotated class  be like:

```
try {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(customer);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

leaving out the details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Following code is used to marshall and unmarshall withot `@XmlRootElement`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.setAge(1);
            c.setName("name");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Customer>( new QName("", "Customer"), Customer.class, null, c), stringWriter);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringWriter.toString().getBytes());
            JAXBElement<Customer> customer = (JAXBElement<Customer>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is),Customer.class);

            c = customer.getValue();

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

}
```

Above code works only if you adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)` on Customer class, or make private all attributes.

Comment: in alternative try to make `private` all attributes , otherwise with or without `XmlRootElement`, JAXB doesn't works

Comment: In the way described above you will not need any other annotations, except `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` but they describe the output

Comment: Is it necessary to marshall before unmarshalling?

Comment: No it isn't. It was only an example to have a xml well formed. @CharlesFollet

Comment: Brilliant! Allows us to marshal/unmarshal our generated classes without having to mangle them manually after generation.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot add XmlRootElement to existing bean you can also create a holder class and mark it with annotation as XmlRootElement. Example below:-

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomerHolder 
{
    private Customer cusotmer;

    public Customer getCusotmer() {
        return cusotmer;
}

    public void setCusotmer(Customer cusotmer) {
        this.cusotmer = cusotmer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Abhishek your solution worked for me, but I had to annotate the Customer field with     
@XmlElement(
            name = "Customer",
            required = true
    )

Answer (score 1):

It is indisputable that the question is very old for an answer, however still hoping someone like me is looking for a simple generic code snippet for the above requirement, hence sharing the working solution for the marshal and unmarshal need.

- **Marshalling XML object to String**

```
public static <T> Optional<String> objectToXMLString(T value,Class<T> clazz,String rootElement) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            JAXBElement<T> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(rootElement), clazz,value);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, sw);
            return Optional.of(sw.toString());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error("XML to String Conversion exception:{}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

- **UnMarshalling String to XML object**

```
    public static <T> Optional<T> xmlStringToObject(String value, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes());
            JAXBElement<T> object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is),clazz);
            return Optional.of(object.getValue());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error("String to XML Conversion exception : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```